# Not seeing output in Cloud Build logs when running with Deployment Manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-deployment-manager

I'm trying to run Cloud Build with Deployment Manager but I'm not seeing the output of commands in the build logs.

```
imports:
  - path: somefolder/**

resources:
  - name: build-something
    action: gcp-types/cloudbuild-v1:cloudbuild.projects.builds.create
    metadata:
      runtimePolicy:
        - UPDATE_ALWAYS
        #- UPDATE_ON_CHANGE
    properties:
      steps:
        - name: 'ubuntu'
          args: ['bash', '-c', 'echo', '====================================================']
        - name: 'ubuntu'
          args: ['bash', '-c', 'pwd']
        - name: 'ubuntu'
          args: ['bash', '-c', 'ls', '-laR']
      timeout: 120s
```

I don't see the output of `echo '====='` or `ls -laR` in the logs in the console:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - Regarding the first step, you need to define it as follow:

```
- name: 'ubuntu'
  args: ['bash', '-c', 'echo "===================================================="']
```

2 - Regarding the last step, I believe that the command does work but that there's indeed no files or directory to list in `/workspace`. When I run this build by creating a `cloudbuild.yaml` file with your exact step and running `gcloud builds submit .`, I see the `cloudbuild.yaml` file listed.